# Base Lightning Component Replication

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am currently trying to use the functionality of the "Contact Support & Ask Buttons" base Lightning Component but I really would like to alter some of it's functionality. Especially because it isn't available to be used for all page types. It looks like the base component code isn't available to be viewed and therefore altered. Is there anyway that I could obtain this code?

Comment: Components in the `ui` and `aura` namespace are available [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components), but the one you're asking for doesn't appear to have a public source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No. We can't access Salesforce's inbuilt component code as Salesforce is not open source for now.

But if you really want you can start development from scratch and if you got stuck community is here to help.